# How can I repeat this section so that two users can enter their details?

Tags: python, loops

I need to repeat this section of code so that the second user can enter their details

```
print ("Welcome to the Dice Game!")

username = input("please enter your Username... ")

f = open("L:/GCSE/Computer Science/Programming/username.txt","r")

# Creates a list. Each item in the list is a string of each line in the text files. It is stored in the variable lines
lines = f.readlines()

# the strings in the list (called lines), also contains escape charachters and whitespace. So this will create a new list, and for each string in the lines list will strip off white space before and after the string
users = [user.strip() for user in lines ]


# checks to see if the username input is also in the users list
if username in users:
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
else:
    print("That is an incorrect username")

passwords = open("L:/GCSE/Computer Science/Programming/passwords.txt","r")

lines = f.readlines()

passwords = [passwords.strip() for users in lines ]

if password in ("F:/GCSE/Computer Science/Programming/passwords.txt"):
    password = print ("Welcome to the Dice Game!")
else:
    print("That is the wrong password")
```

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet? And the third and fourth last lines won't operate as you expect. You aren't reading the file, and assigning the return of print isn't useful.

Comment: also see [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) on how to define functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to repeat a block of code, you can use loops.
A very simple way to do it would be:

```
for _ in range(2):
  # (your code here)
```

To make the code cleaner, I would advice to pack what you have in a function and then calling the function from the loop:

```
def get_user_input():
  # your code here

for _ in range(2):
  get_user_input()
```

Or something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from sekky, you could add a counter that stars at 0 and adds one when player two needs to add the details, something like this:

```
count = 0
def get_user_input():
    if count == 0:
        #player one code
    else:
        #player two code
```